# python 3.6 cannot import .connectionpool from urllib3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, urllib3

if I'm running

```
import urllib3
```

the following error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/christ/Programme/pycharm/projects/projectv01/basics
>   /import.py", line 1, in >module>
>      import urllib3
>
> File "C:\Users\christ\Programme\python\lib\site-packages\urllib3
>   __init__.py", line 8, in >module>
>      from .connectionpool import (
>    File "C:\Users\christ\Programme\python\lib\site-packages\urllib3
>   \connectionpool.py", line 7, in >module>
>
> from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'error'

Please note that I replace < with > ahead of each >module> so the text in-between is still visible
Reinstalling python, pycharm and the libraries hasn't made any difference.

Many thanks for your help
Tomas

Comment: Which version of Python and urllib3 are you using? How did you install urllib3? Can you try with the latest urllib3?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment! I'm using python 3.6.4 and I installed urllib3 with pip. How can I find out what urllib3 version I'm using?

Comment: Interestingly, however, I can import urllib3 with the anaconda IDE spyder successfully (just changed the IDE), but not with my PyCharm. Does anyone have a clue why that is acting this way?

Comment: Maybe you don't have a Python interpreter configured for PyCharm? You should check that the correct interpreter is configured especially if it works in one IDE and not the other.

Comment: I solved this problem by installing python with anaconda that already includes many librabries